# linked in type recommendations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking, communityengine

i am looking to build a ruby on rails application that would be built off of community engine or tog.

id like to know if there was a gem out there that would add recommendation capability to these or any ideas folks out there might have as to building this network

thx

sg

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's going to give you this without getting your hands dirty in source, adding all the recomendations where you want them.

This gem/plugin may help: http://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable